# Other than lxc-info, what other commands can be used to show a container's size?

Tags: lxc

I'm using LXC container and I know lxc-info shows the memory use, CPU usage, IP address etc, but what command can show the container's size? I know memory use is somehow related with size, but I still want the actual numbers because I want to do a precise comparison between VM and LXC containers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is rudimentary, but the only way I can see (and think of) is to navigate to the LXC folder (via commandline or file-manager):

> /var/lib/lxc/

and then right-click and view the size of the contents within the folder. Each folder will be the name of each container.

On average, Ubuntu containers are between 250MB-500MB